# UK tax on an amber painting coming from abroad

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, import-taxes, taxes

Unsure if this is in the right section of Stack Exchange but, I have a family member coming to the UK (from outside of the EU) in the near immediate future.

They will be bringing a painting with them that contains at least 100g of Amber, if not more. It's a gift.

Will they have to declare this upon arrival?
And will they have to pay tax on this?

I am not sure how much the painting costs exactly, but it's less than £100 for sure. It's coming from Ukraine.

Are there any official bodies I can contact in the UK to find out for sure?

Again, apologies if this is in the incorrect section.

Comment: Where do they come from and what is the value of the painting?

Comment: I am not sure how much it costs exactly, but it's less than £100 for sure. It's coming from Ukraine

Comment: Even 100g of raw amber could be worth more than £100. If it is used in a painting then perhaps the rule for importing works of art applies. Perhaps as in [Import VAT and the Free Movement of Goods within the European Union](https://www.artatlaw.com/blogpost/import-vat-and-free-movement-of-goods-within-european-union). *Since 1999, the importation of art, antiques and collectibles items into the UK has been subject to import VAT at the rate of 5%. This is the lowest EU rate.*